# Fail to run SoX using Process in C#

Tags: c#, processstartinfo

I am trying to convert an MP3 file to GSM encoded WAV using [SoX](http://sox.sourceforge.net)

The C# code to execute this is:

```
Console.WriteLine(Cfg.SoxPath); // bin/sox.exe
Console.WriteLine(args); // A rather long argument
var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.FileName = Cfg.SoxPath;
startInfo.Arguments = args;
startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
startInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;

using (Process soxProc = Process.Start(startInfo))
{
    soxProc.WaitForExit();
}
```

The output of the code is:

```
bin\sox.exe  
"D:\VoiceRecorder Soundfiles Storage\MP3 Storage\2012-12-05\227\1\20121205_203436_2103c60a0000134850bfa1bd2c99_8075598.mp3" -c 1 -r 8000 -e gsm-full-rate "temp\227_20120901\SW120006_349990195665213_040154700_20121205203436_20.wav"  
bin\sox.exe FAIL formats: can't open input file `8000': No such file or directory
```

*What causes the command to fail?*

**Things to consider**

- The command runs perfectly when executed directly from cmd prompt
- Arguments (`-c 1 -r 8000 -e gsm-full-rate`) are fetched from an sql server
- Minor changes to argument (e.g. replacing `-e` with `--encoding`) may change error message
- Tried .NET 3.0 and 4.0
- Error message has even included characters not part of arguments (`can't open input file 'ûg'`)
- The same arguments always results in the same error

Comment: @leppie Single quotes yielded the same error I am afraid. Worth a try

Answer (score 1):

I changed the arguments "in between" to:

```
-r 8k -e gsm-full-rate -c 1
```

It started working even though it is the same arguments, just shuffled around a little.
I still have no clue why it wouldn't work from .NET but only from command line prior to these edits.

But now it works.